# large imports from informix servers, using a date filter

Tags: sql, sql-server, informix

We are pulling data from several informix servers on a monthly basis through a odbc connection to a MSSQL database.
Some of these pulls result in 10 million plus records being copied, many of which have previously been imported.
I would like to pull just the previous 31 days of records.
Each record has a date field in the format YYYYMMDD (20140115).
So my question is how can we just grab the most recent 31 days on this date format?

So

```
SELECT field_names
FROM table_name
WHERE date_field Greater then today-31
```

Any advise will be welcome.

Comment: What is the data type of the date_field? date, datetime or char?

Comment: Reiterating comments by @ceinmart: what is the type of the date field? It could be an INTEGER or a bigger-than-INTEGER type; a DECIMAL; a DATE, a DATETIME, or a CHAR or VARCHAR or variations on those themes.  If the type is neither DATE nor DATETIME, then the subsidiary question is "why on earth isn't it a DATE or DATETIME column?"  However, there are answers regardless of the type; but the answers are very different depending on which type you are using.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use something like:

```
... WHERE date_field > TODAY - INTERVAL(31) DAY TO DAY
```

And thanks to **ceinmart**:

Or like

```
... WHERE date_field > TODAY - 31
... WHERE date_field > TODAY - 31 units day
```

or for better treatment by month...

```
... WHERE date_field > TODAY - 1 units month
... WHERE date_field > TODAY - interval(1) month to month
```